# xpath with lxml for Python to get data

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
<th><span class="sic_edu_series_popup {keyword : 'EPS_STOCK'}">EPS</span>
          (SGD) <sup class="sic_legend">a
          , j

    </sup></th>
    <td><strong>1.89766</strong></td>
    <th><span class="sic_edu_series_popup {keyword : 'TRAILING_EPS_STOCK'}">Trailing EPS</span>
      (SGD) <sup class="sic_legend">e</sup></th>
    <td><strong>1.87198</strong></td>
    <th><span class="sic_edu_series_popup {keyword : 'NAV_STOCK'}">NAV</span>
      (SGD) <sup class="sic_legend">b</sup></th>
    <td><strong>18.5449</strong></td>
  </tr>
```

I am trying to extract data for 'Trailing EPS' to get data '1.87198'. There are many data with this format with different name, like EPS, ROE and etc

```
tree.xpath('//th[contains(normalize-space(span), "EPS")]/sup[@class = "sic_legend"]/td/text()')
```

I get nothing out from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `td` element is not a child of the `sup` element. Use the fact that `th` and `td` are *siblings*:

```
//th[contains(span, "EPS")]/following-sibling::td/strong/text()
```

Comment: Thanks. It has the data I wanted but it also contains another two elements. Please refer the edited code above.

Comment: @vindex okay, please try the following: `//th[contains(span, "EPS")]/following-sibling::td[1]/strong/text()`, hope that works.